# Problem with np.where() and conditional operator - " ValueError: For argument "inplace" expected type bool, received type Series."

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Something happened overnight to my favorite np function and I don't understand what?
The below code used to work just fine  and now I get the following error

```
data = {'text':  ['Facotry One fired', 'Second value', 'Match'],
        'H&S': [1, 0 , 0]}
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['text','H&S'])
df_test['H&S'] = np.where(df_test['text'].str.contains('fired'), 0, df_test['H&S'])
```

Expected Outcome

```
data = {'text':  ['Facotry One fired', 'Second value', 'Match'],
            'H&S': [0, 0 , 0]}
    df_test = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['text','H&S'])
```

The error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-d8607dc64cae> in <module>
      4 df_test = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['text','H&S'])
      5 
----> 6 df_test['H&S'] = np.where(df_test['text'].str.contains('fired'), 0, df_test['H&S'])

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in where(self, cond, other, inplace, axis, level, errors, try_cast)
   8916 
   8917         other = com.apply_if_callable(other, self)
-> 8918         return self._where(
   8919             cond, other, inplace, axis, level, errors=errors, try_cast=try_cast
   8920         )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _where(self, cond, other, inplace, axis, level, errors, try_cast)
   8649         applied as a function even if callable. Used in __setitem__.
   8650         """
-> 8651         inplace = validate_bool_kwarg(inplace, "inplace")
   8652 
   8653         # align the cond to same shape as myself

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_validators.py in validate_bool_kwarg(value, arg_name)
    208     """ Ensures that argument passed in arg_name is of type bool. """
    209     if not (is_bool(value) or value is None):
--> 210         raise ValueError(
    211             f'For argument "{arg_name}" expected type bool, received '
    212             f"type {type(value).__name__}."

ValueError: For argument "inplace" expected type bool, received type Series.
```

Comment: For me working well.

Comment: this is so weird - should I reinstall numpy? How?

Comment: If possible, try upgrade pandas.

Comment: same problem...

Comment: Idea - remove pandas and instal new one

Comment: !pip uninstall pandas does not actually execute the command in Jupyter how can I uninstall it?

Comment: maybe you imported `pandas` as `np`

Comment: unfortunately no, I imported as pd.. I have dinsintalled anaconda and reinstalled same problem..

Comment: Is there anyway I can run the same command? at least I know how to do it differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at line 7 of your StackTrace. It contains:

```
lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py
```

So you are calling here the **pandasonic** version of *where* (not
*Numpythonic*).

Then look at the documentation of *pandas.DataFrame.where*, especially at
the order of parameters.
Note that the third parameter is *inplace* and it should be of *bool* type.

Note also that the third parameter in your instruction is a DataFrame column
(actually, just a *Series*).

So probably at the moment when you execute the offending instruction
*np* contains a **DataFrame** (instead of *Numpy* module).

To check this, add `print(type(np))` just before the offending instruction.
Under normal conditions you should get *module*.
But if I am right (somewhere earlier in your code you executed something like
`np = <some DataFrame>`), you wil get *pandas.core.frame.DataFrame*.

If I'm right, inspect your code, find where *Numpy* module is overwritten
with a DataFrame and change *np* in this place with any other name.

Comment: very true! I had mistakenly called a df "np" and that led to the error. Thanks so much for your support.